# Retrieving data from sqlite into a texxtview/edittext

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

[image]

Its not compiling and i have no idea why... New to sqlite and tried to follow some question's answer on stack overflow but not able to figure it out. Modal class is MainDataHelper

Code

```
     MainDataHelper myDatabaseHelper = new MainDataHelper(getActivity());
    myDatabaseHelper.openDataBase();

    String text = myDatabaseHelper.getMostMessagesSent(); //this is the method to query

    myDatabaseHelper.close();

    mMostMessagesSent.setText(text);
    mMostMessagesSent.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Helper

```
public class MainDataHelper extends Activity {
private int TotalMessagesSent;
private int TotalMessagesRecieved;
private int TotalMessages;
private String TotalTimeSpent;
private String MostMessagesSent;
private String MostMessagesRecieved;
private String MostTexted;
private String MostTimeSpent;
private int QuizTaken;
private int QuizTakers;
private int Reviewed;
private int Reviews;

public MainDataHelper() {
    TotalMessagesSent = 0;
    TotalMessagesRecieved = 0;
    TotalMessages = 0;
    TotalTimeSpent = "";
    MostMessagesSent = "";
    MostMessagesRecieved = "";
    MostTexted = "";
    MostTimeSpent = "";
    QuizTaken = 0;
    QuizTakers = 0;
    Reviewed = 0;
    Reviews = 0;
}
public MainDataHelper( int TotalMessagesSent, int TotalMessagesRecieved, int TotalMessages, String TotalTimeSpent,String MostMessagesSent, String MostMessagesRecieved, String MostTexted, String MostTimeSpent,int QuizTaken, int QuizTakers, int Reviewed, int Reviews) {
    TotalMessagesSent = TotalMessagesSent;
    TotalMessagesRecieved = TotalMessagesRecieved;
    TotalMessages = TotalMessages;
    TotalTimeSpent = TotalTimeSpent;
    MostMessagesSent = MostMessagesSent;
    MostMessagesRecieved = MostMessagesRecieved;
    MostTexted = MostTexted;
    MostTimeSpent = MostTimeSpent;
    QuizTaken = QuizTaken;
    QuizTakers = QuizTakers;
    Reviewed = Reviewed;
    Reviews = Reviews;
}

public int getTotalMessagesSent() {
    return TotalMessagesSent;
}
public int getTotalMessagesRecieved() {
    return TotalMessagesRecieved;
}
public int getTotalMessages() {
    return TotalMessages;
}
public String getTotalTimeSpent() {
    return TotalTimeSpent;
}
public String getMostMessagesSent() {
    return MostMessagesSent;
}
public String getMostMessagesRecieved() {
    return MostMessagesRecieved;
}
public String getMostTexted() {
    return MostTexted;
}
public String getMostTimeSpent() {
    return MostTimeSpent;
}
public int getQuizTaken() {
    return QuizTaken;
}
public int getQuizTakers() {
    return QuizTakers;
}
public int getReviewed() {
    return Reviewed;
}
public int getReviews() {
    return Reviews;
}


public void setTotalMessagesSent(int TotalMessagesSent) {
    TotalMessagesSent = TotalMessagesSent;
}
public void setTotalMessagesRecieved(int TotalMessagesRecieved) {
    TotalMessagesRecieved = TotalMessagesRecieved;
}
public void setTotalMessages(int TotalMessages) {
    TotalMessages = TotalMessages;
}
public void setTotalTimeSpent(String TotalTimeSpent) { TotalTimeSpent = TotalTimeSpent; }
public void setMostMessagesSent(String MostMessagesSent) {
    MostMessagesSent = MostMessagesSent;
}
public void setMostMessagesRecieved(String MostMessagesRecieved) {
    MostMessagesRecieved = MostMessagesRecieved;
}
public void setMostTexted(String MostTexted) {
    MostTexted = MostTexted;
}
public void setMostTimeSpent(String MostTimeSpent) { MostTimeSpent = MostTimeSpent; }
public void setQuizTaken(int QuizTaken) {
    QuizTaken = QuizTaken;
}
public void setQuizTakers(int QuizTakers) {
    QuizTakers = QuizTakers;
}
public void setReviewed(int Reviewed) { Reviewed = Reviewed; }

public void setReviews(int Reviews) {
    Reviews = Reviews;
}
```

}

......................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Check the MainDataHelper class. It probably doesn't have a constructor that takes in an Activity/Context. And it also probably doesn't have the openDataBase() and close() methods.

Comment: Could you post your datahelper class?

Comment: look to the edited question @Skemelio

Comment: That is an Activity that you've named MainDataHelper. Nothing to do with SQLite databases. The database helper should extend `DatabaseHelper` class. Read this guide -> https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite#DefineContract

Comment: In your picture, the `getActivity()` part is underline in red. Try passing in `UsageSettings.this`.

Comment: But what about the .openDataBase

Comment: Can u solve my problem please @Ishaan

Comment: I am sorry Akash. I don't use SQLite Databases often. I just noticed the code underlined in red and pointed that out. I wouldn't be able to help you any further.

Answer (score 1):

It's not compiling due to a few reasons.

1. First MainDataHelper does not have a constructor that accepts/takes an Activity. MainDataHelper has two constructors one takes no parameters, the other takes 12 parameters. You have to use one of the available constructors when instantiating a MainDataHelper object.

e.g. `MainDataHelper myDatabaseHelper = new MainDataHelper();` would compile.

2. There is no **openDatabase** method in MainDataHelper, you would either have to add such a method or do away with the line `myDatabaseHelper.openDataBase();`
3. There is no **close** method in MainDataHelper, you would either have to add such a method or do away with the line `myDatabaseHelper.close();`

Considering that you want to use an SQLite database then you will use a sub-class of the SQLiteOpenHelper class that would be invoked from an Activity or a Fragment (or even many of these).

Before even considering writing a line of code you would need to understand you requirements for the database and have some sort of design (schema). Ignoring that and assuming (for demonstration) that you want a simple database with one table called **questions** and has one column called question then the following could be such a class (in this case **MainDataBaseHelper.java**) :-

```
public class MainDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASENAME = "question.db"; //<<<<<<<<<< name of the database
    public static final int DATABASEVERSION = 1; //<<<<<<<<<< version number of the database
    public static final String TABLE_QUESTION = "question"; //<<<<<<<<<< name of the quiz table
    public static final String COLUMN_QUESTION_QUESTION = "question";

    public MainDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASENAME, null, DATABASEVERSION);
    }

    //<<<<<<<<<< Called ONCE when the database is first created (first time an attempt is made to open if)
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_questiontable_sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_QUESTION + "(" +
                COLUMN_QUESTION_QUESTION + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_questiontable_sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

    }

    public long addQuestion(String question) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_QUESTION_QUESTION,question);
        return this.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_QUESTION,null,cv);
    }

    public Cursor getAllQuestions() {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_QUESTION,null,null,null,null,null,null);
    }
}
```

With the above class existing your code could then be (as a simple example) :-

```
    MainDatabaseHelper myDBHlpr = new MainDatabaseHelper(getActivity()); // Instantiate a MainDatabasehelper object called myDBHlpr

    // Add some questions to the questions table
    myDBHlpr.addQuestion("This is the first question");
    myDBHlpr.addQuestion("This is another question");
    myDBHlpr.addQuestion("Yet another question");

    // Now get all of the questions
    Cursor csr = myDBHlpr.getAllQuestions();

    Log.d("DBINFO","There are " + String.valueOf(csr.getCount()) + " questions in the database.");
    // Loop through all the questions
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("DBINFO",
                "Question " +
                        String.valueOf(csr.getPosition() + 1) +
                        " is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(MainDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_QUESTION_QUESTION))
        );
        mMostMessagesSent.setText(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(MainDatabaseHelper.COLUMN_QUESTION_QUESTION));
    }
    csr.close(); //<<<<<<<<<< Should always close Cursor when done with it.

    //mMostMessagesSent.setText(text); //<<<<<<<<<< done in the loop through the cursor (for demonstration very likely only the last question will be seen)
    mMostMessagesSent.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

When run (for the first time) the log would then include :-

> ```
> 11-12 20:17:16.345 1376-1376/? D/DBINFO: There are 3 questions in the database.
> 11-12 20:17:16.345 1376-1376/? D/DBINFO: Question 1 is This is the first question
> 11-12 20:17:16.345 1376-1376/? D/DBINFO: Question 2 is This is another question
> 11-12 20:17:16.345 1376-1376/? D/DBINFO: Question 3 is Yet another question
> ```

Additionally the last question (which may or may not be the last question added) will be displayed in the TextView.

- Note 3 rows would be added to the table each time the above is run.
- Note this is purely intended as an introduction/demonstration there is a great deal more that needs to be done, such as designing the database.

Comment: public static Cursor getAllQuestions(FragmentActivity activity) {
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);

    }

Comment: I copied your getAllQuestions method but in the activity 

            Cursor csr = MainData.getAllQuestions();
 This lina it asked me to make it statis saying it cannot be referenced from a statis context

Comment: but if i change it to static i get error line under this.getWrttableDatabase() saying it shouldnt be static

Comment: You CANNOT just copy that method. You NEED a new class that is a subclass of SQLIteOpenHelper.

Comment: i just didnt have that method to getAllData